# mysql reference not supported to group function

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a MySQL procedure that takes in 2 parameters `par_DateFrom` and `par_DateTo`

I'm getting a nasty error. I'm pretty sure that reusing alias TotalDaysOut to calculate TotalIncome is the culprit. How can I fix this elegantly?

**Error 1247:**
reference `TotalDaysOut`not supported reference to group function

```
BEGIN
SELECT  t.LicencePlate
            ,f.Make
            ,f.Model
            ,f.Year

            ,COUNT(t.LicencePlate) AS TotalTrx          
            ,SUM(DATEDIFF(IF(checkedIn >par_DateTo, par_DateTo, checkedIn) ,IF(checkedOut <par_DateFrom, par_DateFrom, checkedOut))) AS TotalDaysOut
            ,SUM(t.Price* (SELECT TotalDaysOut)) AS TotalIncome
FROM        TRANSACTIONS    t
INNER JOIN FLEET            f
    ON t.LicencePlate = f.LicencePlate
WHERE t.CheckedOut < par_DateTo AND t.CheckedIn > par_DateFrom
GROUP BY t.LicencePlate
            ,f.Make
            ,f.Model
            ,f.Year;
END
```

Comment: what if you use variable to store the value of TotalDaysOut and then use your variable in sum function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your predicates are already verifying that all of the columns referenced in the expression are not null:

```
checkedIn
par_DateTo
checkedOut
par_DateFrom
```

(The predicates in the WHERE clause require all of those to be non-NULL), you could simplify the expression a bit, to reference each column once, rather than twice:

```
DATEDIFF(LEAST(t.checkedIn, par_DateTo),GREATEST(t.checkedOut, par_DateFrom))
```

And (as Gordon already suggested) just repeat that expression where the result is needed.

When we absolutely, positively have to have reference to an alias from a query, the only real option in MySQL is to use an inline view, though this approach has significant performance consequences for large sets.

```
SELECT v.LicencePlate
     , f.Make
     , f.Model
     , f.Year
     , COUNT(v.LicencePlate)  AS TotalTrx
     , SUM(v.DaysOut)         AS TotalDaysOut
     , SUM(v.DaysOut)*v.Price AS TotalIncome
  FROM ( SELECT t.LicencePlate
              , t.Price
              , DATEDIFF(
                  LEAST(t.checkedIn, par_DateTo),
                  GREATEST(t.checkedOut, par_DateFrom)
                ) AS DaysOut
          FROM TRANSACTIONS t
         WHERE t.CheckedOut < par_DateTo
           AND t.CheckedIn  > par_DateFrom
       ) v
  JOIN FLEET f
    ON f.LicencePlate = v.LicencePlate
 GROUP
    BY v.LicencePlate
     , f.Make
     , f.Model
     , f.Year
```

That's less performant, and less elegant, than just simplifying and repeating the expression.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, Thank you Spencer... great explination. I was hoping to avoid repeating the whole expression. Great tip on the simplification of the DATEDIFF function.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that.  You cannot reference a column alias at the same level of the `select` as where it is defined.  I'm not sure what the exact error is but the `(select TotalDaysOut)` doesn't make sense.

So, repeat the expression with the additional multiplication:

```
     SUM(DATEDIFF(IF(checkedIn >par_DateTo, par_DateTo, checkedIn) ,IF(checkedOut <par_DateFrom, par_DateFrom, checkedOut))) AS TotalDaysOut,
     SUM(t.Price * DATEDIFF(IF(checkedIn >par_DateTo, par_DateTo, checkedIn) ,IF(checkedOut <par_DateFrom, par_DateFrom, checkedOut))) AS TotalIncome
```